# custom tableViewController not pushing the data

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have custom table view controller and when i try to push some details to another view , it always push the first element of my array , this is my code i have tried may things ,

i want when i click any cell , the index path row of the cell , will send to other view .

```
#import "ModelsViewController.h"

@interface ModelsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ModelsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    id delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSError*error=nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];



    // Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subjects"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    self.models  =[[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:fetchedObjects]valueForKey:@"modelName"];
    self.modelId =[[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:fetchedObjects]valueForKey:@"modelCode"];
    self.teacher =[[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:fetchedObjects]valueForKey:@"teacher"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 0;

}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // This will create a "invisible" footer
    return 0.01f;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.models count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString * cellIdnt =@"MyCell";

    ModlesTableViewCell *cell =(ModlesTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdnt forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self.teacher objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=      [self.models objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"ShowTimes"])
    {
        ShowTimesTableViewController * timesView =[segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        timesView.modelID=[self.modelId objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];
        timesView.modelNAme=[self.models objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the row value for `myIndexPath` if you try tapping on a cell that's not the first cell?

Comment: always I'm getting =1 even if I'm tapping one cell 2

Comment: That's what you should expect for the second cell. The first cell is 0.

Comment: even i tap on cell no 10 i will get 1 , i should get the value of array self.modelID[9] and the value of it's not 1 , something else .

Comment: Log myIndexPath (not the row) and report what it shows when you select a couple of different rows.

Comment: when i try  NSLog(@"%@",myIndexPath.row) on prepareforsegue i got null

Comment: You need to use @"%ld" for myIndexPath.row, not @"%@".

Comment: also , it showing 0 ( zero )

Comment: In prepareForSegue, log both self.tableView and myIndexPath and see what they give.

Comment: this what they give  0 , AND (null)

Comment: Well, there's you problem. You probably didn't hook up your outlet for the table view.

Comment: myindexpath give 0 and tableView give null

Comment: already i hook up table view , this code from my header file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Comment: That doesn't mean you hooked it up. Did you hook it up in IB? I think not, or it wouldn't be null.

Comment: can you tell me how i can do this thing ?

Comment: In IB, right click (or control click) on the controller icon in your scene, and it will bring up a black window showing all the outlets and other things for your controller. Drag from the open circle on the right side of where it says tableView to the table view.

Comment: Thank You dear i wana express my thanks to you , you are right , i solved .